# How to access local notes database from web browser

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I run my app on webserver:
http://myhost.com/mydatabase.nsf/Home.xsp

On Home webpage I have a button by clicking what I want to access local names.nsf but not myhost.com one.

These lines fail:

```
var namesDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", "C:\notes\data\names.nsf");
var namesDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("Local", "C:\notes\data\names.nsf");
```

This line returns myhost.com Domino database:

```
var namesDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(null, "names.nsf");
```

is there are any other method to open NSF file that is on local PC?

Comment: why not installing a server on the same machine, place the nsf on it and access it via 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, what you're trying is not possible. Your XPages code is running on the server - you may see the output in the browser on your PC, but any SSJS code is running on the server. So it doesn't know where your local names.nsf is. It's like creating a scheduled agent to run on the server and access your local names.nsf - it doesn't know where your PC is.

CSJS will run on your PC, so will know where your names.nsf is, but it won't be able to open the NSF.

In Mail Preferences, it's possible to synchronize contacts to your mail file, which is required to be able to access them in iNotes. If you do that, you can look at your mail file. That's likely to be the best option.

Comment: Paul and Jesse are right. However you could use the href attribute and point to notes:///names.nsf (yes that are 3 slashes) and it will open the local names.nsf in your Notes client ;-) Paul's idea with address sync sounds reasonable unless you are after other parts of the address book

Comment: Thank you stwissel.. At least that is an option to force to open names.nsf in Notes Client by clicking a button on xPages.. .I just thought there is a way to interact with local files through xPages just by passing file path

Answer (score 2):

In that situation, the XPage running on the server has no knowledge of the client machine and the code is running entirely on the server. So, barring a specific corporate setup where you can use the requesting machine's name to do a filesystem reference (which I don't advise), it's entirely distinct.

Presumably, though, you could run the app in XPiNC - if you're willing to put up with all the tradeoffs there, the XPages would then execute on the local machine in a way comparable to normal Notes applications.

Incidentally (and this is unrelated to the server/client barrier), I think that those strings would have their own problem: the backslash in a JavaScript string is an escape character, so you'd have to double them up to resolve as a single backslash, like `"c:\\notes..."`.